# Merge multiple byte array image data into one byte array data set and WriteAllBytes out to a single image output

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

note **uses .net3.5 framework**. no i cannot use any class from System.Windows.Media

**Overview**

I've found the need to take 4 screenshots of content on my screen.

The content is spread across an area larger then my screen area which is 1618px wide and 696px high.

I automate the process of taking screenshots of the 4 areas then i encode the pixels i read from the screen to a byte array with .png data.

I then use `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` to output actual png images to a folder at **"Path**"

**The problem**

i do get all my png images output in an folder and i can successfully view all 4 images . However i need the images to be one large image.

i.e a 3236 x by 1392px image as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxUGB.gif).

in the image you just saw four 1618px by and 696px  squares labeled 1 to 4. this represent the screenshots and order in which they were taken.

Its this same exact order in which i wish the images to be combines and output as a single 3236 x by 1392px image.

in this  class. lets assume that the byte data for image 1 ,2,3 and 4 are already assigned to their respective byte arrays.

```
class SimplePseudoExample
{
 private byte[] bytes1;
 private byte[] bytes2;
 private byte[] bytes3;
 private byte[] bytes4;

private byte FinalByes[];

void CreateTheSingleLargeImage()
{
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Path"+".png",FinalByes);
}

}
```

How can i get my single large image output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to turn them into textures, then use `getPixels` and `setPixels` to do the merging.

```
 tex1 = new Texture2D(2, 2);
 ImageConversion.LoadImage(tex1, bytes1);
 tex2 = new Texture2D(2, 2);
 ImageConversion.LoadImage(tex2, bytes2);
 tex3 = new Texture2D(2, 2);
 ImageConversion.LoadImage(tex3, bytes3);
 tex4 = new Texture2D(2, 2);
 ImageConversion.LoadImage(tex4, bytes4);


 outTex = new Texture2D(tex1.width * 2, tex1.height * 2);

 // we could use tex1.width,tex1.height for everything but this is easier to read

 // setPixels bottom-left is 0,0
 // bottom-left
 outTex.setPixels(0,0,
                  tex3.width,tex3.height,
                  tex3.getPixels());
 // bottom-right
 outTex.setPixels(tex3.width,0,
                  tex4.width,tex4.height,
                  tex4.getPixels());
 // top-left
 outTex.setPixels(0,tex3.height,
                  tex1.width,tex1.height,
                  tex1.getPixels());
 // top-right
 outTex.setPixels(tex3.width, tex3.height,
                  tex2.width,tex2.height,
                  tex2.getPixels());

 byte[] outBytes = outTex.EncodeToPNG();
```

Comment: this looks good. I'll test as soon as i cab turn on my overheated conputer.